# Cannot access 'td' tags beyond first row of table, after extracting/decomposing some 'td' tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this sample table with two rows and four columns, and the first two cells of each row contain PDF files, which is what I want to extract. The other two in each row are ZIP files.

I know I can directly filter for PDF files in the 'findAll' method, but this table is only a small portion. And the entire HTML page is horribly inconsistent (at least for me).

So, I was thinking of removing the tags which didn't contain the PDF files. I didn't understand the results.

When I use 'decompose' to remove the tags which contain ZIP files, only the PDF files in the first row are accessible; the two in the second row don't get printed. However, if I print the entire soup, the PDF files in the second row are still there. I just can't access them using findAll. Printing 'soup.contents' also gives me only the first row.

When I use 'extract' instead of 'decompose', again, only the first row is accessible. However, with this method, the first ZIP file in the first row also gets printed (which I extracted and shouldn't be printed).

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''
<tr>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r1c1.PDF">Chapter 3</a></td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r1c2.pdf">Chapter 3</a></td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r1c3.zip">Protect...stems</a></td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r1c4.zip">Protect...stems</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r2c1.PDF">Chapter 4</a></td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r2c2.pdf">Chapter 4</a></td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r2c3.zip">Busine...Part 1 </a></td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/r2c4.zip">Busine...Part 1 </a></td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for i in soup.findAll('td'):
    print(i.a['href'])                   # This prints all the links correctly

print()

for i in soup.findAll('td'):
    if re.match('.*zip', i.a['href']):
        i.extract()

for i in soup.findAll('td'):
    print(i.a['href'])                  # This prints only the first two PDF files
```

And here's the output (with 'decompose'):

```
# Here are all the links
http://example.com/r1c1.PDF
http://example.com/r1c2.pdf
http://example.com/r1c3.zip
http://example.com/r1c4.zip
http://example.com/r2c1.PDF
http://example.com/r2c2.pdf
http://example.com/r2c3.zip
http://example.com/r2c4.zip

# Only the first row gets printed
http://example.com/r1c1.PDF
http://example.com/r1c2.pdf
```

And here's the last part of the output when I use 'extract':

```
.
.
.

# The first row does get printed, but so does the first ZIP file in it
http://example.com/r1c1.PDF
http://example.com/r1c2.pdf
http://example.com/r1c3.zip
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Programs I'm using:

- Python - 3.4.0
- bs4 - 4.4.0

**EDIT:**

Here are the screenshots of my output:

[image: Output of the script]

The first output is the result of using 'decompose' method, and the second one of 'extract'.

I don't know if it matters, but I didn't actually scrape it off the web. I downloaded the pages first and then scraped from the local copies.

**EDIT 2:**

I want to combine all the PDF files into two separate files (study material and practice manual - the first two columns). I'm planning to include that step in the script itself.

For making the automated renaming easier I want to rename the files with some pattern such as:

```
[study/practice][module] [text of the 'td' tag].pdf
```

For example, '0' would denote a portion of study material, and '1' that of practice manual

So, for 'Chapter 1 Developments in the Business Environment' (included in module 1):

'01 Chapter 1 ... .pdf' would be part of Study Material

'11 Chapter 1 ... .pdf' would be part of Practice Manual.

And chapter 4 (the first one in module 2) of study material would be '02 Ch 4... .pdf'.

The pages on that site are inconsistent and I thought that my job would be easier if I just eliminated all the ‘td’ tags which contained either the links to the ZIP files or just non-breakable space (;nbsp), which is when I ran into this problem of not being able to access all the 'td' elements.

Comment: Can you share the link? Also using your last code snippet I get every url

Comment: Here's the link: http://www.icai.org/post.html?post_id=10160

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the pdfs and zips from the second table after the *id=cpost div* which:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.icai.org/post.html?post_id=10160").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

# get second table after cpost 
table = soup.select_one("#cpost").select_one("table:nth-of-type(2)")

# find all anchor tags where the href value endswith .pdf and .zip
pdfs = [a["href"] for a in table.select("td a[href$=.pdf]")]
zips =  [a["href"] for a in table.select("td a[href$=.zip]")]
print(pdfs)
print(zips)
```

Which gives you:

```
['http://220.227.161.86/28999sm_finalnew_cp-initialpages.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/31899sm_finalnew_vol2A_iniipages.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18905sm_finalnew_cp1a.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21520sm_finalnew_vol2_cp1.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18854sm_finalnew_cp2.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21521sm_finalnew_vol2_cp2.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18855sm_finalnew_cp3.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21522sm_finalnew_vol2_cp3.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/36605sm_finalnew_feedbackform-m1.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/36606sm_finalnew_cp-initialpages-m2.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18856sm_finalnew_cp4.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21523sm_finalnew_vol2_cp4.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18857sm_finalnew_cp5.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21524sm_finalnew_vol2_cp5.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18858sm_finalnew_cp6.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21525sm_finalnew_vol2_cp6.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18859sm_finalnew_cp7.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21526sm_finalnew_vol2_cp7.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18860sm_finalnew_cp8.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21527sm_finalnew_vol2_cp8.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18861sm_finalnew_cp9.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21528sm_finalnew_vol2_cp9.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/31901sm_finalnew_cp-feedbackformvolA.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/36607sm_finalnew_cp-initialpages-m3.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/31900sm_finalnew_vol2B_iniipages.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18862sm_finalnew_cp10.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21529sm_finalnew_vol2_cp10.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18970sm_finalnew_cp11.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21530sm_finalnew_vol2_cp11.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18971sm_finalnew_cp12.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21531sm_finalnew_vol2_cp12.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18863sm_finalnew_cp13.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21532sm_finalnew_vol2_cp13.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18972sm_finalnew_cp14.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21533sm_finalnew_vol2_cp14.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18864sm_finalnew_cp15.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21534sm_finalnew_vol2_cp15.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/18865sm_finalnew_cp16.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/21535sm_finalnew_vol2_cp16.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/29001sm_finalnew_cp-appendix.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/31903sm_finalnew_cp-appendix-pmvolab.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/29000sm_finalnew_cp-feedbackform.pdf', 'http://220.227.161.86/31902sm_finalnew_cp-feedbackformvolB.pdf']
['http://www.mediafire.com/file/7g7zhhlzmd2u49u/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmenP1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/tx0dhvlkx9w518s/P5Ch1DevelopmentSBusinessEnvironmentP1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/751095mme1hd5z7/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ifn2nn57czr5djm/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/trf1adc5a1gr4at/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP3.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ofjv0pu00v35ivc/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP4.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/us454ahc99llili/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP4.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/etps8fn6y26qyyn/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP5.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/659coi5bhg8ku50/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP5.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/2fhzegia69op9ao/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/rrbciytpktmh121/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ivtvwvknl5w7bc7/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ba87eg665dtwaui/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/lyzb1yic8l7alst/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart3.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/8iln8yigbzrla3k/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart3.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/7aafaoqgsq5dg6u/P5Ch3PricingDecisions.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/fbmdhlqm8ey3aue/P5Ch3PricingDecisions.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/0ixhgb0x07qu1an/P5Ch4BudgetP1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/wqlk53ol26j4lmm/P5Ch4BudgetP1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/b9dsw8sudsud7eg/P5Ch4BudgetP2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/mrbw44z2mru2tnw/P5Ch4BudgetP2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/hfndpfthdfm7l7s/P5Ch4Budget_3.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/03yzz48no2ttbta/P5Ch4BudgetP3.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/usxz01xiuw6rgaj/P5Ch4Budget4.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/qoyjgu61luvsd71/P5Ch4BudgetP4.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/m3h6qm2gevdmx4n/P5Ch5StandardCosting.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/wdj8nsl7to2u6cz/P5Ch5StandardCostingPodcast.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/x9ypv4oxx573ea4/P5Ch5StandardCostingPart1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ax1taa1ahaga2w3/P5Ch5StandardCostingPart1.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/z0z0pxp5l44qnz4/P5Ch5StandardCostingPart2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/h8stxmsqcdqum9q/P5Ch5StandardCostingPart2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/v33bcec4ep6ulxc/P5Ch6CostingofServiceSector.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/i9y7gebccovv852/P5Ch6CostingofServiceSector.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/bd61s151fgk1xbs/P5Ch7TransferPricing.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/iwf47hp8bb6wtdq/P5Ch7TransferPricing.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ihn7dz4okrvl8c6/P5Ch8UniformCostingAndIFC.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/44nqn834616kqvb/P5Ch8UniformCostingAndIFC.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/hfyr8y6w18klua8/P5Ch9CostsheetPAAndReporting.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/dnxlsmifismp269/P5Ch9CostSheetPAAndReporting.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/ef27t3y4ly7zsqa/P5Ch11LINEARPROGRAMMINGPart2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/66zwcr87sxu8r08/P5Ch11LINEARPROGRAMMINGV5R.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/03340dc0g94t3r9/P5Ch11LINEARPROGRAMMINGV5R.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/i3dcrrbcfcy7xqh/P5Ch11LINEARPROGRAMMINGPart2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/j870no55rq8qu55/P5Ch11Transportation_rev.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/vm75wz1j93s284c/P5Ch11Transportation.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/0qibqc72f2zdf6g/P5Ch12AssignmentProblem.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/7iqrbl2ze6wh7mp/P5Ch12AssignmentProblem.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/nds6vcp6b7ws36h/P5Ch13CriticalpathAnalysis.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/wurwuaspw9ne954/P5Ch13CriticalpathAnalysis.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/stxrr65qth1jmi3/P5Ch14PERT.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/mzlg290e1gy3ce5/P5Ch14PERT.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/jhad7r6qxexkvug/P5Ch15Simulation.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/af2r0p99m36uvd4/P5C15SimulationV2.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/vl59gzd8szy83rw/P5Ch16LearningCurveTheory.zip', 'http://www.mediafire.com/file/439dd5eec4c6u2i/P5Ch16LearningCurveTheory.zip']
```

Which matches exactly what you see on the page.

If you just want then from column 1 and  and to rename using the td text:

```
# get second table after cpost
table = soup.select_one("#cpost").select_one("table:nth-of-type(2)")
rows = table.select("tr")

for row in rows:
    td1 = row.select_one("td:nth-of-type(1)")
    td2 = row.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)")
    l1, l2 = td1.select_one("a[href$=.zip]"),  td2.select_one("a[href$=.pdf]")
    if l1:
        print("Found zip {}".format(l1["href"]))
        print(td1.text)
    if l2:
        print("Found pdf {}".format(l2["href"]))
        print(td2.text)
    print()
```

Which gives you:

```
Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/31899sm_finalnew_vol2A_iniipages.pdf
Initial Pages 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21520sm_finalnew_vol2_cp1.pdf
Chapter 1 Developments in the Business Environment

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/751095mme1hd5z7/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP2.zip
Developments in the Business Environment Part 2 


Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/ofjv0pu00v35ivc/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP4.zip
Developments in the Business Environment Part 4 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/etps8fn6y26qyyn/P5Ch1DevelopmentsBusinessEnvironmentP5.zip
Developments in the Business Environment Part 5 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21521sm_finalnew_vol2_cp2.pdf
Chapter 2 Decision Making using Cost Concepts and CVP Analysis 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/ivtvwvknl5w7bc7/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart2.zip
Decision Making using Cost Concepts and CVP Analysis part2

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/lyzb1yic8l7alst/FP5Ch2DecisionMakingAndCVPAnalysisPart3.zip
Decision Making using Cost Concepts and CVP Analysis part3

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21522sm_finalnew_vol2_cp3.pdf
Chapter 3 Pricing Decisions 




Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21523sm_finalnew_vol2_cp4.pdf
Chapter 4 Budget & Budgetary Control 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/b9dsw8sudsud7eg/P5Ch4BudgetP2.zip
Budget and Budgetary Control Part 2 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/hfndpfthdfm7l7s/P5Ch4Budget_3.zip
Budget and Budgetary Control Part 3 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/usxz01xiuw6rgaj/P5Ch4Budget4.zip
Budget and Budgetary Control Part 4 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21524sm_finalnew_vol2_cp5.pdf
Chapter 5 Standard Costing 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/x9ypv4oxx573ea4/P5Ch5StandardCostingPart1.zip
Standard Costing - Part 1 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/z0z0pxp5l44qnz4/P5Ch5StandardCostingPart2.zip
Standard Costing - Part 2 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21525sm_finalnew_vol2_cp6.pdf
Chapter 6 Costing of Service Sector 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21526sm_finalnew_vol2_cp7.pdf
Chapter 7 Transfer Pricing 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21527sm_finalnew_vol2_cp8.pdf
Chapter 8 Uniform Costing & Inter-firm Comparison 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21528sm_finalnew_vol2_cp9.pdf
Chapter 9 Cost Sheet, Profitability Analysis and Reporting 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/31901sm_finalnew_cp-feedbackformvolA.pdf
Feedback Form 



Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/31900sm_finalnew_vol2B_iniipages.pdf
Initial Pages 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21529sm_finalnew_vol2_cp10.pdf
Chapter 10 Linear Programming 

Found zip http://www.mediafire.com/file/03340dc0g94t3r9/P5Ch11LINEARPROGRAMMINGV5R.zip
Linear Programming – Part 2 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21530sm_finalnew_vol2_cp11.pdf
Chapter 11 The Transportation Problem 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21531sm_finalnew_vol2_cp12.pdf
Chapter 12 The Assignment Problem 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21532sm_finalnew_vol2_cp13.pdf
Chapter 13 Critical Path Analysis 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21533sm_finalnew_vol2_cp14.pdf
Chapter 14 Program Evaluation and Review Technique 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21534sm_finalnew_vol2_cp15.pdf
Chapter 15 Simulation 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/21535sm_finalnew_vol2_cp16.pdf
Chapter 16 Learning Curve Theory 

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/31903sm_finalnew_cp-appendix-pmvolab.pdf
Appendix

Found pdf http://220.227.161.86/31902sm_finalnew_cp-feedbackformvolB.pdf
Feedback Form
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated this earlier. Your answer's great if all I wanted was to extract the PDF files. Please see my EDIT 2 to know why I wanted to remove the 'td' tags containing the ZIP files.

Comment: By the way, is it just me or are you too not able to access the 'td' tags beyond the first row? For the purposes of testing, I chose three or four rows (so that there were PDF files as well as some ZIP files and non-breakable spaces), which gave me the results I've posted in the question.

Comment: @Mahesh, `...16LearningCurveTheory.zip` is the last file in the table so if I could only access the first you would not see that. I still son't see why you want to remove anything as you can parse whatever you want from the source including the td text

Comment: I think your solution is enough for now. However, I'm still curious about its behaviour. Why does it not give access to all the other 'td' elements, even though they're present in the soup (which is evident if I print the soup)?